Finding count of ID's in table cross-referenced with data from second table
I'm trying to find the count of Transaction ID's associated with Client ID's enrolled in certain purchasing agreements for products. I have two tables - one has the raw transaction data (Transaction ID, Product Type, Client ID), the other has the enrollment data for those purchasing agreements (Product Type, Client ID).
Both of these tables have duplicate values in Program Type and Client ID, and I'm trying to find the count of transactions associated with each client/program combination. The issue is that clients have purchasing agreements for multiple products, and transactions for products that they do not have agreements for as well, so I need to filter those out.
What I'm ultimately trying to get is a PivotTable with Product Type, Client ID, and then the count of associated transactions. Something that looks like the below, but as a PivotTable:

I've tried creating relationships between the Product Type and Client ID columns by creating extra worksheets with only those columns as tables. I then created relationships from [Transactions] -> [Product Type] <- [Purchasing Agreements], and I've done the same with the Client IDs.
I can create a Pivot Table with all data sources available because of this, but when I try to get a count of Transaction ID's in the Transactions table against the Client ID's it just gives me a count of all Transaction ID's on every row with a popup saying, "Relationships between tables may be needed." There are no other columns with shared values I can create relationships between.
I do have access to SSMS if this would be easier to do in there, but I have a very limited grasp of SQL. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

What about countifs() ?

I might be doing it wrong, but the issue I'm running into is that I can't filter out the clients who are buying products they're not enrolled for if I'm looking at all the combinations, so I would need to manually create countifs() for each set of clients enrolled in each program. The issue being I have hundreds of products and over 10,000 clients, most of whom are enrolled in multiple agreements, which makes it a pretty massive job to do manually.

Use unique() to get a list of clients, then iferror() with countifs() to get the counts.

Took some time to process, but I got it working with those. Thanks for the help, I appreciate it.

@Areth are these Ids numerical? Which version of Excel are you using?

@Areth If you're using Excel under Windows, please see whether this is helpful: https://exceloffthegrid.com/combining-multiple-tables-in-a-pivottable/. If you're still looking for other ways, I could post a solution using FILTER and XLOOKUP.

It would help us help you if you shared a sample of both tables and the expected result with that.
